# Why is Madara supposedly dead?

Tags: naruto

According to Kurama, the Juubi's Jinchuuriki Wouldn't die when the Bijuu are extracted from him thanks to the Gedou Mazou.

[image: You can live if you die]

So how could Madara have passed away?

Comment: Is this based on something recent or from for example: a latest episode or something? Could you maybe expand your question a bit more.

Comment: Yes, this is based on naruto chapter 656 when the tailed beast where extracted from Obito

Comment: It might be best if you edit that into your question.

Answer (score 6):

That's because the Gedo Mazou itself was extracted as well (and sealed on the new moon on the other dimension).

#### Spoiler

> [[image: Gedo Mazo being extracted]
>
>  <sub>Click the image for a larger version</sub>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pK2FV.jpg)
>
>  We can see the Gedo Mazo getting caught up in the Rikudo Chibaku Tensei, while Madara getting spit out.

Madara didn't have the Gedo Mazou in him to provide life force when all of the Bijuu were extracted.